# Integer addition with overflow on a struct

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

There is the [ULARGE_INTEGER union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383742(v=vs.85).aspx) for compilers that don't support 64 bit arithmetic.

What would happen in the following code if the addition on the last line overflows?

```
ULARGE_INTEGER u;
u.LowPart = ft->dwLowDateTime;
u.HighPart = ft->dwHighDateTime;
u.LowPart += 10000; //what if overflow?
```

Related question:
[What is the point of the ULARGE_INTEGER union?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915752/what-is-the-point-of-the-ularge-integer-union)

Comment: unsigned integers are guaranteed to wrap around.

Comment: @HenriMenke which means the carry would not be added to the `HighPart`?

Comment: Have you tried that? In my opinion only LowPart will overflow (wrap), it won't affect HighPart.

Comment: I'm confused... why even ask this question?  Couldn't you simply try it?

Comment: @H Walters What would that prove?

Comment: @Roland I've added a couple of duplicates. In sure there are many more. This isn't really related to the struct. You are simply performing unsigned wrap around on a single variable. The compiler just sees one variable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If overflow in `LowPart` doesn't in practice spill into `HighPart`, then it proves he can't produce the correct 64-bit sum using that method; _even if_ someone opines that he can.

Comment: @H Walters How could there be any spillage?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why are you asking me?  I'm not the one that had the question.

Comment: @H Walters Your comment suggested that there was a possibility that incrementing one variable might result in a different variable being modified.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Epistemically, yes.  That's directly implied by the question... see the second comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ULARGE_INTEGER` is composed of two unsigned values.  Unsigned values are guaranteed to wrap round, so in some sense they *can't* "overflow".

If wrap round *does* occur, `u.LowPart` will end up being less than 10,000.  What you probably want is:

```
u.LowPart += 10000;
if (u.LowPart < 10000) u.HighPart++;
```

... but what compiler still doesn't support 64-bit integers these days?  They have been required by the C++ standard since 2011, and the C standard since 1999.  So what you *really* want is:

```
u.QuadPart += 10000;  // Forget about legacy compilers that doen't support 64 bits.
```

Comment: Understood. I'm just trying to understand how `ULARGE_INTEGER` is to be used if you only have 32 bit arithmetic. So you have to check for overflow and increment the `HighPart` as you did in your code fragment?

Comment: @Roland : Yup.  Similarly if you  are trying to emulate 1024 bit arithmetic with 64 bit values.

Comment: Then the following linked reply is actually incorrect, since it says that I could just perform addition on the `QuadPart` on a 32 bit compiler https://stackoverflow.com/a/14932949/480894

Comment: @Roland: why do you think it is incorrect? 32 bit compilers provide 64 bit arithmetic since ages, exactly as compilers for 16 bit platforms provide arithmetic on 32 (or even 64) bit types.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I understood that `ULARGE_INTEGER` was intended to be used on compilers that *don't* support 64 bit arithmetic. Is this assumption incorrect?

Comment: It's correct, I'm just saying that virtually all 32 bit compilers targeting Windows in the last 15+ years do support 64 bit arithmetic - of course operations on 64 bit types aren't compiled to single instructions (and most complex ones, such as divisions, are typically translated in a call to a division function provided by the C runtime), but at least you don't have to explicitly worry about implementing them. That's why I say that the linked answer is correct even for 32 bit compilers - unless of course you have a truly ancient one (but then it should be explicitly stated in the question).

Comment: For example, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261215(v=vs.60).aspx) you can see that it was supported un VC++ 6 - that's almost 20 years ago!

Comment: @MatteoItalia I got it. `uli.QuadPart += 10000;` will only work if your compiler supports 64 bit arithmetic, otherwise you have to check for overflow as in Martin Bonner's code.

Comment: I still work with a C cross compiler on a 16 bit microprocessor, and I'm fine.

Comment: Without long long (64) , and I'm fine. ANSI X3.159-1989 standard [ANSI]

Comment: @TomKuschel: good for you, but here we are talking about 32 bit compilers targeting Win32. The problems, the tools and the general environment are different.

Comment: @Roland: exactly, which means that, given the widespread availability of built-in 64 bit arithmetic, this particular instance of this pattern is mostly an historical artifact.